# Django efficient way to operate on cache values using redist

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I want to operate on cache values using Redis cache system. Redis has many good operations itself, but cache module in Django doesn't support them. I know for using Redis methods I can import Redis and create a client and use these methods, but using this method we must create client each time and try to connect to the Redis server.  Is this an efficient way to use Redis in Django in large scale requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other people have faced the same issue and have created Redis cache backends for Django so you can just import one of those, eg

https://django-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/